# Can LD access the data at an address?

Tags: c, linker

I'm writing some code for a project that uses a Kinetis processor. These processors have a Flash Config Field which is stored in flash at a particular address. If the wrong value gets written to that field, you can lock yourself out of your chip for good.

My code for this consists of a packed struct, an instance that specifies the .flashConfig section, some static asserts to ensure the struct is the required size, and the #define that gets written to the FSEC field (the important one) is as expected. Then in the linker script I have that section stored in the correct bit of flash. Additionally I have an ASSERT to see if I have the correct amount of data in that section.

This is all pretty good, but I'm still nervous (I've seen these chips gets themselves locked up, on several occasions now). What I want to do is add an extra assert to the linker script, something like:

```
ASSERT(BYTE_AT(0x40C) == 0xBE);
```

Is that possible?

I considered using objdump / objcopy to get dump this from a .bin in a post build step. However I'm building this on windows, so no grep / awk which would be nice and easy. Other people will also have to build this, so I don't want to rely on cygwin being installed or what not. Plus this is a little more removed than the linker, and therefore could easily be missed if someone removes the post_build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to rely on cygwin being installed or what not.

Write a C program that performs the same check `objdump` and `grep` would have done.

> Plus this is a little more removed than the linker, and therefore could easily be missed if someone removes the post_build script.

Make the verification program invoke the linker, and then verify the result. That is, instead of

```
${LD} -o foo.bin ${LDFLAGS} ${OBJS} && ./post_build foo.bin
```

do this:

```
./build_and_verify -o foo.bin ${LDFLAGS} ${OBJS}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a decent option.